# Replacing Django admin templates with apps in subdirectories

Tags: python, django

I've organized my project as the following:

```
myproject/
    urls.py
    settings.py
    views.py
    templates/
    apps/
        __init__.py    <-- needed in order to be identified as a package
        exampleapp/
             __init__.py
             admin.py
             models.py
             urls.py
             views.py
        exampleapp2/
        ...
```

In my settings.py INSTALLED_APPS, the apps are name 'apps.exampleapp1', 'apps.exampleapp2' with the dot (.) notation indicating that the modules are in subdirectories. According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates), if I wish to override or extend the admin templates for an app I need to make a directory in templates named 'admin/appname/modelname/' but I've tried both 'admin/apps/exampleapp/' and 'admin/apps.exampleapp' but neither work. Where in the django.contrib.admin code can I find how templates are replaced or, more simply, what directory path do I need to have in order to extend or replace an admin template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you organize your apps is inconsequential. The app's name is still just its immediate foldername: "exampleapp" or "exampleapp2".

So your admin template overrides should go in "/templates/admin/exampleapp/modelname/" and "/templates/admin/exampleapp2/modelname/".

Answer (score 0):

This might be old but I hope this solution help someone

(Django 1.8.1)

First at the top of your settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Then:

Copy the admin template you want to extend from to the folder you created in myproject/template

After doing that, specify the directory in setting.py TEMPLATE:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',],},},]
```

After all that I realized that I had this in the file I wanted to use:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}
     {{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('My Site') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
    <h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('Admin Page') }}</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

But it keep showing the default Django title and header.
These lines are where I found the solution:

**{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('My Site') }}**

**{{ site_header|default:_('Admin Page') }}**

As soon as I deleted *site_title|default:_*    and    *site_header|default:_*, it showed what i wanted.

Again, I hope this help someone out there.